# Разбор строки математического выражения с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Скрипт считает некоторую формулу, результаты вычисления собирает в строку для вывода пользователю. Это выглядит примерно так:

```
 // Формула для примера, "из головы" и может быть абсолютно любая:
 $calc = $x*($y+$w+$z)+$x($y+$x+$w*$x);    

 // После вычислений получаем текстовую строку такого вида:
 $visual = "5*(0+1+0)+5*(0+5+1*0)";
```

Нужно преобразовать эту строку, очистив её от всех `0`, а так же их множителей. Пока что удалось добиться удаления нулей, их множителей и знака `+` перед ними, но осталась проблема: если ноль сразу после скобки, то нужно удалить `+` за ним. В идеале - еще убрать скобки, если внутри только одно число.

```
// Регулярное выражение я упростил для наглядности, допустим, что все числа целые:
$regexp = "/\+?(?:[\d]+\*)?0/";
$visual = preg_replace($regexp, '', $visual);

echo $visual; /* 5*(+1)+5*(+5) */
```

Можно ли добиться того, что я хочу с помощью одного шаблона или нужно делать 2-3 прохода по строке?

Comment: Это надо не регулярками делать, а нормально парсить. Невозможно проверить скобочную поаледовательность на правильность при помощи регулярок.

Comment: что значит "нормально парсить"?

Comment: если вложенных скобок не будет, то можно что-то навертеть с помощью условных подмасок `(?(cond) yes-regexp|no-regexp )`, разве нет?

Comment: Укажите требуемый финальный ("очищенный") вариант строки из примера.

Comment: В данном случае `5*1+5*5`,но это потому, что в примере в скобках осталось по одному числу. Скобки специально упрощать не нужно, то есть вариант `5*(1+1)+5*5` тоже считается очищенным. Чуть ниже добавил то, что мне нужно, но за 4 шага

Answer (score 1):

Слегка изменил пример, чтоб охватить большее число вариантов:

```
$visual = "5*(0+1+0+1)+5*(0+5+1*0)+5*(0)";
```

Если делать в несколько шагов, то:

```
// убираю нули, множитель и лидирующий плюс
$regexp = "/\+?(?:\d+\*)?0/";                         
$visual = preg_replace($regexp, '', $visual);           // 5*(+1+1)+5*(+5)+5*()

// убираю `+` сразу после скобки
$regexp = "/(?:\()\+/";                           
$visual = preg_replace($regexp, '(', $visual);          // 5*(1+1)+5*(5)+5*()

// убираю скобки, если внутри только одно число
$regexp = "/\((\d)\)/";
$visual = preg_replace($regexp, '\1', $visual);          // 5*(1+1)+5*5+5*()

// убираю скобки и множитель, если в скобках ничего
$regexp = "/\+?\d+\*\(\)/";
$visual = preg_replace($regexp, '\1', $visual);          // 5*(1+1)+5*5
```

Последний вариант - "очищенный" полностью.

Comment: А вот с этим примером уже [не справится](https://ideone.com/t25Ika): `5*(1+0+1+0+1)+5*(1+0+5+0*3)+(0)*5`.

Comment: Осталось только цикл добавить, чтобы можно было применить замену 1 например к результатам замены 2 и так до тех пор, пока есть хоть одна замена в цикле.

Comment: @stribizhev `+(0)*5` у меня быть не может, не волнуюсь. а `0*3` тоже избегаю искусственно. формулы все же я пишу, не пользователи :) @ReinRaus да, спасибо, оно и так в цикле бегает, я не стал тут усложнять.